# Generate findbugs error on printStackTrace statement

Tags: java, maven, logging, findbugs

Is there a way in findbugs/maven combo that will generate error if exception.printStackTrace statement is seen in the code.

We use log4j in code and I want all team members to log the error using log4j as stdout is normally discarded for many of the jobs and log file gets other relevant information. For development process, using maven profiles, we make sure log goes to stdout so that IDEs like eclipse show the output of code. For production build, stdout logger is removed.

Best way to detect accidentally introduced printStackTrace is to fail the build. Can I achieve this using findbugs? Any other suggestions are also welcome.

Comment: http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-4.3.0/rules/logging-java.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Writing a detector to search for uses of "System.out.println" using Findbugs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7704252/writing-a-detector-to-search-for-uses-of-system-out-println-using-findbugs)

Comment: @Brett, thanks for the link, it certainly is in right direction, but I just want to suppress printStackTrace to log the errors in the log file.