# Adding custom detectors in findbugs

Tags: java, findbugs

I am trying to add a detector which will detect System.out.println() occurrences. As explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7704252/writing-a-detector-to-search-for-uses-of-system-out-println-using-findbugs) post, I've written the detector class, findbugs.xml file and messages.xml file.
I created a jar which contains my detector class, findbugs.xml and messages.xml files. I added this jar in my eclipse environment (window->preferences->java->findbugs->Plugins and misc. Settings). But it is showing invalid entry.

Detector class:

```
    package findbugs.custom.detector;
    import edu.umd.cs.findbugs.BugInstance;
    import edu.umd.cs.findbugs.BugReporter;
    import edu.umd.cs.findbugs.bcel.OpcodeStackDetector;
    import edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.ClassDescriptor;
    import edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.FieldDescriptor;
    public class CallToSystemOutPrintlnDetector2 extends OpcodeStackDetector {


private BugReporter bugReporter;


public CallToSystemOutPrintlnDetector2(BugReporter bugReporter) {
    super();
    this.bugReporter = bugReporter;

}


public void sawOpcode(int seen) {
    if (seen == GETSTATIC){

        try {
            FieldDescriptor operand = getFieldDescriptorOperand();
            ClassDescriptor classDescriptor = operand.getClassDescriptor();
            if ("java/lang/System".equals(classDescriptor.getClassName()) && 
                    ("err".equals(operand.getName())||"out".equals(operand.getName()))) {
                reportBug();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //ignore
        }
    }
}

private void reportBug(){
    this.bugReporter.reportBug(getBugInstance());
}


private BugInstance getBugInstance() {
    return new BugInstance(this, "MY_CALL_TO_SYSTEM_OUT_BUG", 10)
        .addClassAndMethod(this)
        .addSourceLine(this);
}
}
```

findbugs.xml file:

```
    <FindbugsPlugin>
    <Detector class="findbugs.custom.detector.CallToSystemOutPrintlnDetector2" speed="fast" />
    <BugPattern abbrev="SYS_OUT_P" type="CALL_TO_SYSTEM_OUT" category="CORRECTNESS" />
    </FindbugsPlugin>
```

messages.xml file:

```
    <MessageCollection>
    <Detector class="findbugs.custom.detector.CallToSystemOutPrintlnDetector2">
    <Details>
    <![CDATA[
    <p>This detector warns about SYS_OUTs used in the code. It is a fast detector.</p>
    ]]>
    </Details>
    </Detector>
    <BugPattern type="CALL_TO_SYSTEM_OUT_BUG">
    <ShortDescription>sysout detector</ShortDescription>
    <LongDescription>Found sysout in {1}</LongDescription>
    <Details>
    <![CDATA[
    <p>This is a call to System.out.println/err method. </p>
    which should be avoided.
    ]]>
    </Details>
    </BugPattern>
    <BugCode abbrev="SYS_OUT_P">Found sysout</BugCode>
    </MessageCollection>
```

How can I correct this?

Comment: PMD already has [a detector](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-4.3.0/rules/logging-java.html#SystemPrintln) that does this.

Comment: But as far as my knowledge is, PMD works on source code and Findbugs works on Bytecode. My aim was not to write a detector for detecting System.out.print, but to understand how to write a detector using bytecode and add it to findbugs.

Answer (score 1):

The error is because of the package hierarchy. My detector class was inside `findbugs.custom.detector` package, but when I created the jar (using eclipse) I was only selecting the required files (findbugs.xml, messages.xml, detector class).
Hence the package information was not included in the jar. Our XML files read the detector class using the attribute `class` of the `Detector` tag whose value was `findbugs.custom.detector.MyDetectorClass`.
So when XML files try to read the detector class, they could not find `findbugs.custom.detector` package. 
To build a jar with the package information in it, select the whole project and then create a jar with required files.